# How to Run Mobile originated call perl script on Emulator

Tags: android, perl, android-emulator

I was trying to run Mobile originated call perl script on Emulator but getting error while running the script:

Below is the script:

**Mo_call.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use New_MO.pm; 
for(my $i=0; $i<=4;$i++)
{
  New_Mo::call_Originate();

  }
```

**New_MO.pm**

```
package New_MO;

sub call_Originate
{
  system("adb -s $device_id shell service call phone 763726728");
  sleep 10; 
  system("adb -s $device_id shell input keyevent 4");
  system("adb -s $device_id shell input keyevent 3");

}  
1;
```

I am new for this things so if possible then please let me know where I am doing mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try using

```
use New_MO;
```

instead of

```
use New_MO.pm;
```

If this doesn't help, would you please share the error message you're getting?

Comment: @ Mikko .. Sorry but by mistake instead of writing "use New_MO;", i have written "use New_MO.pm;". Sure I am going to share my error msg with you.

Comment: I am getting this error while running the above script Result: Parcel(Error: 0xffffffb6 "Not a data message")

Comment: That doesn't look like perl error to me. Maybe it's the adb program complaining?